# angularjs ui-grid : input text filter is not working properly for multiple grids on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I've 2 `angularjs ui-grid` on a page. I am using following custom filter to filter column data by input text.

```
filter: {
    condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue) {                                        
    searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(/[^\w\s\d\.\-\ ]/g, '');                                        
    var strippedValue = (cellValue + '').replace(/[^\w\s\d\.\-\ ]/g, '');                                                                               
        return strippedValue.indexOf(searchTerm) >= 0;
          }
    }
```

Now here the column definition is shared between two grid via `angularjs` custom directive. In a directive grid id is different for both grid.

Please find below screenshot:

[image]

Here, if I type something in custom filtered column in one grid, the same also reflected in second grid. And this is happening only for custom filtered columns. It's working fine for built-in `cellFilter` columns.

**How do I make input text filter works in respected grid only ?**

Comment: Have you found a solution? Do you have two separate controllers for the two different grids? Does Sorting work on both grids?

Comment: @fauverism - No I haven't found the solution. There is only one controller and one column definition which is being used in two grids. Yes sorting works fine on both grids.